# Iconos en select

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, cakephp

segui un ejemplo de cpen o algo así, no recuerdo bien como se llama la pagina y mi pagina no muestra las imagenes que necesito. 
Este es el ejemplo: `https://codepen.io/brapastor/pen/BWyomB`

estos son los codigos:

home.ctp

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-width="fit">
                <option  data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-mx" value="es"></span> Español'>Español</option>
                <option data-content='<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" value="en"></span> English'>English</option>
            </select>
```

js

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $(function () {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        });
...
```

default.ctp

```
   echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
   echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-datepicker3');
   echo $this->Html->css('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min');
   echo $this->Html->css('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/0.8.2/css/flag-icon.min');

   echo $this->Html->script('jquery-3.3.1');
   echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
   echo $this->Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min');
   echo $this->Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min');
```

por si sirve de algo uso cakephp 2.x

Comment: Te falta agregar las extensiones a los CDN's

Comment: En cake eso no es necesario, al decir $this->Htnl->css estoy diciendo que es un css.

Y lo mismo con script lo reconoce como un js, sino no me funcionaria las validaciones y demás estilos que tengo en la pagina.

Comment: No es necesario al llamar a un archivo local, si llamas a la URL completa si debes incluir las extensiones. Intenta agregarlas